# Application Insights Extract Nested CustomDimensions

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have some data in Application Insights Analytics that has a dynamic object as a property of custom dimensions. For example:

```
|        timestamp        |  name   | customDimensions                 | etc |
|-------------------------|---------|----------------------------------|-----|
| 2017-09-11T19:56:20.000 | Spinner | {                                | ... |
                                         MyCustomDimension: "hi"
                                         Properties:
                                             context: "ABC"
                                             userMessage: "Some other"
                                      }
```

Does that make sense? So a key/value pair inside of customDimensions.

I'm trying to bring up the `context` property to be a proper column in the results. So expected would be :

```
|        timestamp        |  name   | customDimensions                 | context| etc |
|-------------------------|---------|----------------------------------|--------|-----|
| 2017-09-11T19:56:20.000 | Spinner | {                                | ABC    | ...
                                         MyCustomDimension: "hi"
                                         Properties:
                                             context: "ABC"
                                             userMessage: "Some other"
                                      }
```

I've tried this:

```
customEvents | where name == "Spinner" | extend Context = customDimensions.Properties["context"]
```

and this:

```
customEvents | where name == "Spinner"  | extend Context = customDimensions.Properties.context
```

but neither seem to work. They give me a column at the end named "Context" but the column is empty - no values.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Added a picture for clarifying the format of the data:

[image: Application Insights Data]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**edited to working answer**:

```
customEvents
 | where name == "Spinner"
 | extend Properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
 | extend Context = Properties.context
```

you need an extra `tostring` and `todynamic` in here to get what you expect (and what *i* expected!)

the explanation i was given:

> Dynamic field "promises" you the *upper/outer* level of key / value access (this is how you access customDimensions.Properties).
>
> Accessing *internal structure* of that json depends on the exact format of customDimensions.Properties content. It doesn’t have to be json by itself. Even if it looks like a well structured json, it still may be just a string that is not exactly well formatted json.

So basically, it by default won't attempt to parse strings inside of a dynamic/json block because they don't want to spend a lot of time possibly trying and failing to convert nested content to json infinitely.

I still think that *extra* `tostring` shouldn't be required inside there, since `todynamic` should already be allowing both string and dynamic in validly, so i'm checking to see if the team that owns the query stuff can make that step better.

Comment: Spot on - Properties does not contain a well-formatted JSON, so it can't be parsed to a dynamic value

Comment: John and @EranG - my bad on the representation of the data in Stack Overflow. It is indeed well-formatted JSON. I've attached a picture in the original question so you can better see what I'm seeing in the Analytics portal.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks sooo much.. just to expand on the answer from John. We needed to graph duration of end-points using custom events. This query made it so we could specify the duration as our Y-axis in the chart:

```
customEvents
 | extend Properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
 | extend duration = todouble(todecimal(Properties.duration))
 | project timestamp, name, duration
```

Comment: aside: if you're storing numeric values, you should put them into customMeasurements (metrics) instead of properties (you can send them the same way you do custom properties, you don't need to use `trackMetric`).  then you can use them in other tools like Metrics Explorer.